# Laravel 5.3 CORS with JWT auth

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, cors, laravel-5.3

I have an issue with Laravel 5.3 CORS. I searched a lot on this issue, and found many recommending barryvdh for CORS. This however didn't work, and I found people mentioning that this could be caused by the use of tymondesigns jwt-auth module. Some suggests bypassing it by setting

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Authorization, Content-Type');
```

in the api.php file. This results in responses like:

```
Failed to load https://example.com/api/v1/members/1: Method PUT is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Methods in preflight response.
```

In attempt to resolve this issue I added

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE, PUT');
```

to the above 2 lines. However this left me with a new issue:

```
PUT https://example.com/api/v1/members/1 403 (Forbidden)
Failed to load https://example.com/api/v1/members/1: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'https://example.com' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 403.
```

Any suggestions how to go about this?

Comment: I'm pretty sure the problem is with authentication. You should definitely keep the PUT in the Allow-Method headers and check if the correct Authorization token is being passed. Do other auth-only routes work for you?

Comment: The authentication part of it is working just fine on localhost where the api and client share domain.

Answer (score 0):

If this is only happening on production, be sure to check your nginx configuration files. This is likely due to the following settings:

```
add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";
add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff";
```

Try commenting these out to see if that fixes the situation, then un-comment one by one, and make adjustments as necessary.

Comment: I should have mentioned that I am running on an Apache server.

Answer (score 0):

You can use three-way to solve this problem:

1) Use barrvay/laravel-cors

```
'supportsCredentials' => false,
    'allowedOrigins' => ['http://localhost:4200'],
    'allowedHeaders' => ['Content-Type','Accept','Authorization'],
    'allowedMethods' => ['GET','POST','PUT', 'PATCH', 'OPTIONS', 'DELETE'],
    'exposedHeaders' => ['Content-Disposition', 'x-total-count', 'x-filename'],
    'maxAge' => 0,
    'hosts' => ['*'],
```

2) Use Chrome Plugin ([Moesif CORS](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/moesif-origin-cors-change/digfbfaphojjndkpccljibejjbppifbc?hl=en)) for localhost

3) Build a CORS middleware and putt all of cors header inside it

```
    namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class Cors {
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        return $next($request)
            ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
            ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS');
    }
}
```